# how to map a Json object to LinkedHashMap in dart with toJson() and fromJson() methods?

Tags: json, dart, linkedhashmap

I need to map below Json Object to **LinkedHashMap cases;** 
i Know this kind of object conversion,

```
class CountryInfo {
  String flag;

  CountryInfo({this.flag});

  CountryInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    flag = json['flag'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['flag'] = this.flag;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I need to know Timeline.fromJson and toJson() for below object,

```
class Timeline {
  LinkedHashMap<String, int> cases;
}
```

This is the object that i need to know.

```
{
"cases":{
     "4/2/20":151,
     "4/3/20":159,
     "4/4/20":166,
     "4/5/20":176,
     "4/6/20":178,
     "4/7/20":185,
     "4/8/20":189,
     "4/9/20":190,
     "4/10/20":190,
     "4/11/20":198,
     "4/12/20":210,
     "4/13/20":217,
     "4/14/20":233,
     "4/15/20":238,
     "4/16/20":238,
     "4/17/20":244,
     "4/18/20":254,
     "4/19/20":271,
     "4/20/20":304,
     "4/21/20":310,
     "4/22/20":330
    }
}
```

Comment: use this to convert json to dart https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Normally i'm using that converter to convert json to dart. but it doesn't give what i want. This object has dynamic key. thats why i want to assign this object to LinkedHashMap. any way thank you for comment.