# anyone know about Dart dynamic variables ? and it's behaviour?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class TestDynamic {
  dynamic myVariable;
}
```

above code is the class for Dart language.

Comment: Think you need to do a bit of studying https://dart.dev/tutorials

Comment: thank you! do you have a answer for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570522/how-to-map-a-json-object-to-linkedhashmap-in-dart-with-tojson-and-fromjson-m

Answer (score 1):

**dynamic** is a type underlying all Dart objects. You shouldn't need to explicitly use it in most cases.

**dynamic**: can change TYPE of the variable, & can change VALUE of the variable later in code.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost a rudiment, but at the same time it is sometimes used.
This was once the **pride** of developers.

You can read about how all this was originally conceived here.

Why Dart Types Are Optional and Unsound
http://dartdoc.takyam.com/articles/why-dart-types/

> > Background: Dart is a dynamically typed language, and proud of it

And here...

http://dartdoc.takyam.com/articles/optional-types/
Optional Types in Dart